# Bind multiple values to a textblock

Tags: c#, binding, windows-phone-8.1, textblock

I bind a appointment object to a Textblock:

```
TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Path = new PropertyPath("Subject");
textBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);
textBlock.DataContext = appointment;
```

The result is, that the Subject of the appointment is shown in the Textblock.

Now I want that the time of the appointment is shown in the textblock before the subject of the appointment.
Can anybody help me modifying my source code to get that result?

Comment: I don't think multiple binding is supported on WinRT. But you can simply add a property to your appointment object and use the getter to concatenate the values

Answer (score 1):

I am probably missing something obvious, but couldn't you use one of the following:

- create a property that combines the values (from other properties) and can parse out changes back to those source properties.  Then bind to that instead.
- use a ValueConverter and bind to that.  Just search on "C# ValueConverter" to get info on how to use it.

There are probably a few others, but those come to mind on first thought.  If neither of these will work for you, let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is always the MultiBindingBehaviour from the Cimbalino toolkit, it's explained here https://www.pedrolamas.com/2013/05/17/cimbalino-windows-phone-toolkit-multibindingbehavior/

It allows to give multiple input params for one output.
The toolkit can be installed through NuGet